# Spring security concurrent session is not working as desired

Tags: session, spring-security

Instead of restricting one session per user,it is restricting one session for

whole application.

So if one user is logged in noone can login .

Here is my configuration

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
        <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" />
     </session-management>
```

And i even added listener in web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check"
            login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" success-handler-ref="myLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
        <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/choices/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

     <session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
            <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
                max-sessions="1" />
        </session-management> 
    </http>

    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="customDaoAuthenticationProvider">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.test.connect.web.login.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="myLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.test.connect.web.login.MyLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: How do you test this? Not from the same browser, I hope?

Comment: @AleksandrM Ya ofcourse from the different browser

Comment: Show your full spring-security configuration.

Comment: @AleksandrM https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=62ED565D5FB4426D!152&authkey=!ANZhrRtYijt4X8A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the configuration you provided, which includes a custom AuthenticationProvider, and the problem you are having I would guess that you are returning a custom UserDetails implementation that does not properly implement the equals and hashCode methods.

Please ensure that you have properly implemented equals and hashCode on any custom UserDetails implementation as these methods are used to look up if a user contains active sessions.

Comment: Hi I'm not using any custom Userdetails implementation .I'm returning the following org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails in retriveUser method.

Comment: Are you certain that your customDaoAuthenticationProvider is returning unique users then? If it is accidentally returning a User object with the same username it will cause a similar issue. If that doesn't help, try enabling debug logging and attaching the logs for the first and second logins.

Comment: According to logs everything is working properly. The only problem is my browser.Sometimes IE7 is not redirecting after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to highlight here, make sure the equals and hashCode methods return is true. if the methods is not returning true it will not kill or terminate the existing session.